# add username and current date in destination folder robocopy

Tags: powershell, robocopy

I would like to use robocopy to copy folders to destination D:\username\currentDate.
How do I get system username and date. I'm new to this. So, an explanation is appreciated.
Thanks.

Comment: Run robocopy /? on the shell of your choice (:

Comment: %username%  to test in cmd Echo %username%